# Regular expression for 6 to 32 alpha numeric characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression with the following rules :

1. Alpha-numeric with at least 1 number and 1 letter
2. Allows some special and Spanish characters.
3. Should not allow spaces

I have come up with the following which does everything but prevent spaces :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z~!@\$\^\-_\+\|\.\?\u005b\u005d\u00e1\u00c1\u00e9\u00c9\u00ed\u00cd\u00f3\u00d3\u00fa\u00da\u00f1\u00d1\u00fc\u00dc\u00bf\u00a1\u2014]).{6,32}$
```

How can this be modified to flag spaces?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see about [negated or complemented character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: cant you pass it through a series of filters in the case where one expression does not satisfy all requirements.  Even if there is a solution that elegantly

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so:

`^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z~!@\$\^-_+\|.\?\u005b\u005d\u00e1\u00c1\u00e9\u00c9\u00ed\u00cd\u00f3\u00d3\u00fa\u00da\u00f1\u00d1\u00fc\u00dc\u00bf\u00a1\u2014]){6,32}$`

It would seem that in your current regular expression, you have a wild card matcher (`.`) which should be matching the space you do not want to match. The wild card operator appears in 3 places, `^(?=.\d)`, `(?=.[a` and `14]).`. Thus, your regular expression, as is, should allow at most 3 white space characters, one before the initial numbers, on after the initial set of numbers and one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to negate space characters.

---

### Example negative lookahead

`(?!^.*\s)`

### Full regex

`^.*(?![^!-~\u005b\u005d\u00e1\u00c1\u00e9\u00c9\u00ed\u00cd\u00f3\u00d3\u00fa\u00da\u00f1\u00d1\u00fc\u00dc\u00bf\u00a1\u2014])(?!^.*\s)(?=^.*\d)(?=^.*[a-zA-Z]).*$`

I made modifications to the regex, so that it is more in line with typical password validation techniques.

Specifically, I changed your positive lookaheads so that they start with `^.*`, so that they validate the entire string, not just whatever is to the right of the current position.

I also separated them out, so that each one is validated, rather than a single character class which is intended to have multiple requirements, but can be satisfied by a single one.

As a final note, I changed the ASCII inside the character class to the following range: `!-~` which covers all letters, numbers, and symbols except for space.

Comment: This seems to allow all special characters.

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted special chars :) Change the `!-~` range in the first character class if you want to restrict which special chars are matched.